# The review badge progress indicator shows a badge I already have

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, badge-progress

...  and it tells me that I need a negative number of reviews to get that badge.

[image]

Also reported by user [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) in SOCVR: [*It looks like I can get a silver badge for review if I only review -2372 more*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49551673#49551673)

And here is one from SFF from [Mithical](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/33591):

[image]

Just to be clear, this is not a case of me tracking badges or missing badges for other queues. This is what my badge progress looks like for [/review/low-quality-posts/stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) here on MSE:

[image]

(sorry for not having done enough reviewing there)

There is no gold badge there.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you have the badge for *all* queues?

Comment: @Mast no, on SO I'm short of H&I and intend to keep it that way.

Comment: That may be part of the source of the issue. You both have it and are tracking it. A different one that you already have with the same name. That still shouldn't give negative numbers, but it may be a start.

Comment: @Mast Hmm, I expect that page to show me badges for that review queue. Not all the other queues. I've added an extra screenshot for a queue here on MSE

Comment: Hmmm, yes, it gives me negative numbers on badges I already have on other sites too.

Comment: Can reproduce on [CR.SE/review/close/stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHFm2.png).

Comment: Basically there's 2 bugs here. 1) It gives a negative number for badges already earnt where it shouldn't. 2) It doesn't show how many reviews are left for the next badge, which seems to be the purpose of that part of the overview.

Comment: It seems fairly universal, I see it on Spanish.se too.

Comment: Apparently someone forgot to end a `</p>` so it just says `</p`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fixed.  This bug was introduced through a typo in a dark mode fix PR.

The code looked  like:

```
@if (earned) {
    <p>EARNED</p
} else {
    <p>UNEARNED</p>
}
```

The missed closure of the tag closure means `</p } else { <p>` was interpreted as a the tag closing by both the Razor parser the browser.

As a result, users who had earned the badge got the following rendered DOM:

```
<p>EARNED</p>
UNEARNED
<p></p>
```

As the reviewer of the PR, this one's on me.  I feel like the reason both I and the author missed this was that it fails so subtly for users who haven't earned the silver or gold badges, omitting them rather than emitting incorrect HTML.

Comment: Seems to me like the `<p>` and `</p>` tags should be factored *out* of the conditional, since they are "common". That would prevent this problem and others like it in the future. Limit your conditional code to only that which needs to be conditioned.

Comment: @CodyGray If you did that, you would have to think about accidentally adding spaces inside the `<p>`. Your output would basically be inline level instead of block level, so you would probably have to squeeze everything onto one line to make it clear. Also, you would lose any chance of adding additional classes based on the conditional.

Comment: @CodyGray Razor syntax moves between C# and HTML based on the presence of tags, so there’s got to be some element inside the brackets or things get convoluted and brittle.

Comment: I assume with us in a revision >  2020.6.4.36968 ?

Comment: @rene Yep, the fix is in now and looks correct for me on SO.